# What classes this as a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, unclear

Last week I found [this 'question'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85122/sleep-less-than-one-millisecond), which isn't a question at all as it doesn't actually *have* a question in it:

[image]

It's more of an attempt to provide a solution for `sleep`ing a process for less than one millisecond, but it's still not a question. I [discussed this question on the SO Tavern Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21481238#21481238) and the users that were in there at the time agreed with me that the question should be VTC'd as 'Unclear what you're asking'.

However I also thought that as the post is of high-quality, it's not fair to close it and potentially delete it; instead I thought that it should be *locked* instead, and so I raised a custom flag.

Unfortunately the moderator who reviewed it didn't agree to this, nor did they agree that the question should be closed:

[image]

The moderator's response was:

> I don't think this needs to be closed at all.

..implying that they do not think there's anything wrong with the question, why?

This question isn't a question, it shouldn't be open (in my opinion) and I'm surprised it's lasted as long as it has.

So, what makes this post a question?

Comment: A question doesn't require a question mark, the actual question is implied here and you've discerned what it was. If you want to add an unnecessary question mark at the end then go for it, but that's not a reason to close it is it?

Comment: @Ben No, this question is essentially an answer and question *as a question*, it should've been asked as a question with the OP giving their answer *as an answer*. The main issue here is that the moderator who reviewed my flag thought the question was okay. For the record I've now upvoted the question as it was edited by rene ti actually *ask* a question.

Comment: TBH, I'm not even convinced that such a mechanism works any better than calling Sleep() or a timed-out wait on a synchro object.  There are no test results to demonstrate the functionality.

Comment: What makes it not a question? Your flag states that you think it should be closed, or that it should be locked, and that some other people agree with you, but it never says *why*.

Comment: @BilltheLizard So if I make a question with 'how do I do x' and give the answer in the question body, it's okay?

Comment: Of course not. That's not what I said at all. When you flag something you need to tell us why.

Comment: I don't get this; ever since I posted this question, the question concerned has gone from 38 votes to 35 votes, meaning three people agree with me, but however the general consensus here is that is *was* a question, just not properly asked. Again, I believe this was an issue that we generally don't want study a question to actually *find* the question within it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've edited the question to remove the answer and did change the style a little bit so it reads as a question.

The question was self [answered by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/85143/578411). I edited that answer as well.

After my edit [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205955/doc) edited the title into shape.

We now have a perfect question with a lot of upvotes that is relevant and clear for future readers.

There is indeed no need for this question to be closed. If a question is salvageable by editing please do. Downvoting, flagging and closing is only for posts that have no value now or in the future.

Comment: I wanted to edit it but I was concerned that my edit would've been rejected on the basis that it changed too much. The question was indeed useful although it wasn't properly asked, which is why I asked it to be locked instead of closed (locking it apparently increases the question's visibility whilst closed questions reduces it).

Comment: That is a concern indeed. Just try to find some high rep with direct editing privileges. The SO Tavern chat room can help with that as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is absolutely a question. It even has a title that already makes it very clear what the question is: "Sleep less than one millisecond". While it doesn't end in a question mark, it's a clear problem statement. And it's actually much more reader friendly than the more verbose "How do you sleep less than one millisecond?", which adds nothing useful.

If the title is not enough, the problem statement is repeated in the first sentence (emphasis added):

> On Windows, you have a problem you typically never encounter on Unix. That is **how to get a thread to sleep for less than one millisecond**.

I see nothing wrong with the way this question was asked.

Comment: It's an opening statement, rhetorical, not an actual question. The problem with this question is that nothing was actually asked here, it just answers the title. You *did* read the *previous* version of the question, right? Not the current version. Even if you did, 40 (currently) users disagree with you on that one, questions should be *obvious*, we shouldn't have to nitpick.

Comment: Yes, I read the previous version. Where do you get 40 users from? The question has 38 upvotes and 3 downvotes. You're really looking for a problem where there's none. There are plenty of questions that actually **are** bad that could use some attention.

Comment: Read the first comment: http://puu.sh/fZmyg/32691309dd.png